# How to write a file from photoshop and resize it - Photoshop Script

Tags: resize, export, photoshop

I'm an app developer, and I use photoshop to make my icons. But there is a really annoying part... You have to export about 10 images with different sizes. And I thought that I maybe could use Photoshop Script to do this for me. Is there any way to make a plugin that can first resize the image to a given size and then export it, and then do this a couple times.

Thanks, Anton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT!

What you need is to automate the annoying "copy, resize, export" process. Just wiped all the instructions I had here bout Actions, since I remembered the Generator tool.

You are gonna love it.

Here is a great tutorial to learn how to use it:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/10/15/create-assets-for-multiple-scale-factors/

It's a tutorial intended for designers crafting stuff for retina displays, but scroll down to "Generate and Enjoy", they use icons as an example so even better for you.

Enjoy

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I wrote an algorithm to calculate the sizes, and now I can just save the name of the layer and in my next app icon project just paste it in and it will directly save the images as I want! Wait, gonna tell my mom!

Comment: This answer would be better if it included the pertinent parts of that article, rather than linking off-site.